# Prove a function vanishes almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a Borel measurable function on the real line.Show that if $\int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx=0$ for all rationals a,b such that $\infty<a<b<\infty$ then $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.

I want to use proof by contradiction. Firstly assume that $m\left\{x|f(x)\neq 0\right\}\neq 0$,since this function can be both nonnegative valued and negative valued ,I don't know how to choose proper rational numbers $a,b $ to derive the contradiction.

Comment: To prove, you can look at what kind of structure the sets over which $f$ integrates to 0 form. I.e. do they form a $\sigma$-algebra, and if so what does that mean?

Comment: Probably should assume $f$ is locally integrable.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer After proving that the collection of sets you pointed above is a $\sigma$-algebra,then we can use Lebesgue differentiation theorem.Is that what you mean or is there other method to approach it?

Comment: After proving that it is a $\sigma$-algebra, can you think of any other $\sigma$-algebra generated by rational intervals?

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer This $\sigma$-algebra is consists of  all the Borel sets. By what theorem,we can get the desired result from this fact?

Comment: This already proves it. You wanted to show that it vanishes $a.e.$ and the sets where it vanishes contain at least all Borel sets.